# Leaflet draggable Zoom Control

Tags: leaflet, drag-and-drop

My goal is to make Zoom Control movable in a leaflet map.
For this I tested this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Creating Draggable DOM Elements</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../leaflet/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="../leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 700px;
      width: 700px;
      border: solid 1px black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>

    var map = L.map('map', {
      center: [50.3271, 7.0381],
      zoom: 5
    });

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    var attribution = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-attribution')[0];
    var draggableAttribution = new L.Draggable(attribution);
    draggableAttribution.enable();

    var zoom = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-zoom')[0];
    var draggableZoom = new L.Draggable(zoom);
    draggableZoom.enable();

    console.log(attribution);
    console.log(zoom);

    console.log(draggableAttribution);
    console.log(draggableZoom);

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This one does not work for the zoom control.

I tested that later for attribution. Dragging works here.

What am I doing wrong with the zoom control?

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong, this is simply not possible with zoom control. It captures all mouse events and stops their propagation. If you would want to achieve that, you would have to significantly modify (extend) event handling in zoom control.